# Prolog. Reverse nodes in a tree

Tags: recursion, tree, prolog, binary-tree

I want to reverse the nodes in a binary tree like this :

```erlang
[[ [ [[],1,[]], 5, []],
   7,
   [ [], 3, [[],4,[]]]],
 6,
 [ [ [], 10, []],
   8,
   [ [[],9,[]], 11, [[],2,[]]]]]
```

[image]

I can only use this ABN representation as lists and the following constructors and selectors of the abstract data type.

```erlang
empty([]).
root([_,N,_], N).
hi([HI,_,_],HI).     %left son 
hd([_,_,HD],HD).     %right son
maketree(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD]).
```

I want to know how could I make a swap predicate like this `swap(A4,B).` that working like this:

```erlang
?- swap(A4,B).
B=[[[[[],2,[]],11,[[],9,[]]],8,[[],10,[]]],6,[[[[],4,[]],3,[]],7,[[],5,[[],1,[]]]]]
```

Thanks !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you describe in general terms how the swap would work? If so, you can translate that into Prolog. Start with describing how to swap nodes in an empty tree (or a tree of one node). Then recursively define swapping a tree in terms of subtrees.

Comment: Reconsider to use a three-element list to represent a node, rather use `t(HI,R,HD)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an *abstract* data type, you can treat your interface predicates as opaque:

```erlang
% empty([]).
% root(Tree, Root).
left_child(Tree,Left):- hi(Tree,Left).  
right_child(Tree,Right):- hd(Tree,Right).  
mktree(Top,Left,Right,Tree):- maketree(Top,Left,Right,Tree).
```

To swap two nodes in a tree, just

```erlang
swapped_tree(Tree, SwappedTree):-
    left_child(Tree, Left ),
    right_child(Tree, Right ),
    root(Tree, Root ),
    % and then combine them in a simple way,
    mktree( ..., ..., ..., SwappedTree).
```

It is in Prolog just like it is in English.

But the nodes there stayed the same. To have the new tree to be the full mirror of the original, you'll want to treat the child nodes too *in the same way* as you do the whole tree, before creating the new, mirrored tree:

```erlang
mirrored_tree(Tree, MirroredTree) :-
    .... ,
    .... ,
    .... ,
    mirrored_tree( ..., ... ),
    mirrored_tree( ..., ... ),
    .... .
```

Using the predicate you are still writing (as if it were already written) to solve sub-parts of the full problem which are *of the same nature* as the full problem, and recombining the results in some *simple* way to get the solution of the full problem, is the essence of recursion.